# Concat @JsonProperty values - Java Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Can I concat two properties in one setter?

Like:

```
@JsonProperty("value1" + "value2")
public void setFinalValue(String concat){
    this.finalValue = concat;
}
```

If yes, how can I concat with Jackson?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I suggest you create two setters and one getter:

```
@JsonProperty("value1")
public void setValue1(String value1) {
    this.value1 = value1;
}

@JsonProperty("value2")
public void setValue2(String value2) {
    this.value2 = value2;
}

public String getFinalValue() {
    return value1 + value2;
}
```